# Spinning Bar Using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, json, progress-bar, afnetworking

I have this method that is reaching a webservice and bring me back a JSON. The method is working fine, the problem is that I want a spinning bar progress while this method is not bringing anything yet.

```
-(void)loadJson{



    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kGetURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        self.json = JSON;
        [myTableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON){

        NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"didn't reach the server"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];



    }];

    [operation start];


}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UIActivityIndicatorView, here called mySpinner, and add it to the screen. Then:

```
-(void)loadJson{

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kGetURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        [mySpinner stopAnimating];    

        self.json = JSON;
        [myTableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON){
        [mySpinner stopAnimating];

        NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"didn't reach the server"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];



    }];

    mySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [mySpinner startAnimating];

    [operation start];


}
```